# How to remove 60+ million rows of Data using Temp Table using Postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql

Am looking to delete a vast amount of data in our database, we are not sure where to place the deleted data for now but to have a separate copy is what we are looking to do.

I explored using a CTE originally but there are some concerns about the use of a CTE for such large data so have opted for a temp table but am having difficulty getting it working.

Am also trying to wrap it in a transaction so we have the option of rolling back should we want to:

```
begin; -- typically faster and safer wrapped in a single transaction
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmpold AS ( ERROR: syntax error at or near "t" Position: 51)
SELECT t.*
--into temporary table tmpold (also tried this but ERROR: syntax error at or near "t" Position: 51
FROM   play t
where t.play_created_on > NOW() - interval '1 years'; 
delete t.* from play t 
inner join tmpold on t.play_id = tmpold.play_id;
select count (*) from tmpold 
ROLLBACK;
```

Cant understand why it is not working, I want to select a set of values from a play table into a temp table and then delete the data from the play table using the values from the temp table.

Not sure whether the temp table is the correct way, I want to retain the deleted data from the play table in a separate table until we can decide what we do with it.

Comment: I bet the syntax error is from the `DELETE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of things you need to change.

A temp table is not what you want, they are removed as soon as the connection that created them closes, and they cannot be accessed from any other connection. Use a regular table instead.

You have an unneeded left parenthesis (that is unclosed) in the CREATE TABLE AS statement; it's just `CREATE TABLE <tblname> AS <SELECT statement>`, not `CREATE TABLE <tblname> AS (<SELECT statement>)`.

Your delete syntax is wrong in two ways. First, you select rows, not columns, to delete, which means you just `DELETE FROM (tablename) as (alias)`, not `DELETE (alias).* FROM (tablename) as (alias)`. Second, regular JOIN syntax like this is used for SELECT statements, not DELETE*; instead, use a sub-select in the WHERE and the planner will set up the required join, something like:

```
delete from play t
WHERE t.play_id IN (select tmpold.play_id from tmpold)
```

*Caveat - [`DELETE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) *can* have a regular JOIN clause if it also has a USING, but it's not needed here.

One other thing that looks weird to me but may be as intended - typically in the situation like this, the intent is to move *old* records out of the main table. The WHERE clause on your initial CREATE TABLE AS SELECT would instead move the *most recent* year's worth of records out of the the main table, while leaving all the old records. If that wasn't the intent, you probably want to change `t.play_created_on > NOW() - interval '1 years'` to `t.play_created_on <= NOW() - interval '1 years'`

Comment: that worked a treat, I did the sub select instead. Yes you are correct on the > being incorrect, I was just testing a smaller subset of data and forgot to change that back. In terms of the actual query itself, I will be testing for in excess of 500m rows, is there a good way of batching this so its not done in one lump?